# Telegram group read messages from another bot

Tags: telegram-bot

I have 2 bots in 1 Group (bot A and bot B).

When a user sends a message to the group, both bots can see it.

But if any of the bots A or B send a message to the group, none of the bots can read the other bot message.

Is it possible that bot can read other bots messages? or messages sent by himself?

The "getUpdates" function returns only mesages from users, not bots, is there a way how to receive group messages sent by bots?

Thanks

Comment: Which library are you using? It really can its limitation to avoid recursive reading of own bot message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not. This is a limitation set by Telegram itself.

It is stated clearly in the official Bot documentation under [FAQ Section.](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesnt-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots)

> **Why doesn't my bot see messages from other bots?**
>
> Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this, we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.